# Remove Docker images and Containers on Linux

Tags: linux, docker

I am running Docker on a Linux centos 7 machine.

I have the following:

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nexct-approval-service-image   latest              9a6cc95e4a5b        21 seconds ago      557MB
<none>                         <none>              f5264c7714fc        16 minutes ago      1.59GB
ng-nexct-approval-ui-image     latest              be6452e5e4fd        21 minutes ago      25.9MB
<none>                         <none>              34be479d08be        21 minutes ago      1.59GB
<none>                         <none>              a288baba8130        31 minutes ago      1.55GB
<none>                         <none>              dbc9c501ae96        39 minutes ago      25.9MB
<none>                         <none>              27abd9aaecd8        39 minutes ago      1.59GB
<none>                         <none>              77cf54bee6e9        2 hours ago         557MB
<none>                         <none>              95dcbba9943a        3 hours ago         557MB
<none>                         <none>              6278cfc0c974        3 hours ago         557MB
<none>                         <none>              40254b2f468d        4 hours ago         25.9MB
<none>                         <none>              b87ba4139b0d        4 hours ago         1.59GB
node                           latest              7f312bedcea0        13 hours ago        944MB
openjdk                        14                  cdc43cc23d2d        6 days ago          511MB
nginx                          alpine              ecd67fe340f9        12 days ago         21.6MB
```

I want to clear all the images and containers, so I run the following commands:

```
sudo docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)
sudo docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

But when I run each command, I get the following error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers
```

**Question**

How do I set permission to allow my user to remove images and containers?

Comment: You need to run __all__ the docker commands with sudo, this includes the two in `$(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run docker commands wiht `sudo` or add the user running the commands to `docker` group if you would like to run `docker` commands as non-root user.

[Manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)